# CloudFront + EC2 + Apache + PHP

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Would setting up Amazon's CloudFront with a custom origin as an ec2 server have any performance increase to serving PHP with Apache? Basically serving all the dynamic content through CloudFront.

For reference all my static content is already being served through CloudFront on a seperate domain.

IF that is possible and provides a performance increase could you do something like CloudFront which routes to an Elastic LoadBalancer which routes to an EC2 instance which has nginx as a front (still have some static content not on cloudfront) which in turn routes all php to Apache's mod_php.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudfront isn't great at serving dynamic content, although it's better than it used to be.  Cloudfront doesn't accept POST requests.  Also it strips querystrings out of GET requests unless you change the setting.  Ref [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?CustomOriginBestPractices.html).

Comment: hey, i think cloudfront accepts querystrings just need to enable it
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

Comment: @Jianhong thanks for the update.  Looks like they've improved cloundfront since I wrote this.